# Alfresco Share: Using ALfresco.Util.PopupManager in my customized Login page

Tags: share, alfresco

I am working on customizing Alfresco Share for Business purpose. So I have Customized and Overridden the default login page. But now I want to show the pop up a message for invalid logins in the same way as ALfresco Share does. Going through the core files I found it makes use of `ALfresco.Util.Popupmanager` and `Alfresco.Util.Message`. So I included the `alfresco.js` file and copied the portion of the code from `slingshot-login.ftl` where it uses `ALfresco.Util.Popupmanager.displayprompt`, but when I deploy it, rendered the page and issued an invalid login I got the following error:

```
Alfresco.messages.global is null  var globalMsg =
  Alfresco.messages.global[p_messageId];
```

Kindly help.

Answer (score 1):

What is your `p_messageId`?

This is should work:

```
Alfresco.util.PopupManager.displayPrompt(
{
    text: "My message here"
});
```